# Storing textfield data into a dictionary in swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, textfield

I have two text fields where the user will input the model and year of their car and store it as the key value pairs for the dictionary.
I have the dictionary key as the company. The values for this dictionary another dictionary with the make as the key and year for the value.

```
var myDictionary = ["Audi": [:], "Chevy": [:], "Ford": [:], "Mazda": [:], "Lexus": [:], "BMW": [:] ]
```

How would I go about storing this data?

Answer (score 0):

There must be a selection process to select the brand of the car.
You can add value to the dictionary like this.

```
var myDictionary: Dictionary = ["Car1": textfield1.text, "Car2": textfield2.text]
```

Comment: Thank You! This helped alot!